# What modern editors compete with emacs/vi?

Tags: emacs, editor, vi, paradigms

Emacs and vi are the traditional editors of the programming gurus.  But, have any modern editors been able to displace these two in terms of extensibility and text editing productivity?

I know editors such as Eclipse and commercial editors provide language specific advantages such as intellisense and refactoring, though this is not quite what I'm looking for.  My question is more along the lines of an innovative editor paradigm at a more general level, such that I can use it for many disparate languages, extend it for other tasks, etc.

Comment: I'd try emacs 23.1. Plenty modern, innovative and extensible for me.

Comment: I think any answer is pretty much up to individual taste.  You might have better luck asking here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Actually the latest Emacs is 23.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sublime Text is a relatively new and very good editor for Windows.

[www.sublimetext.com](http://www.sublimetext.com)

Comment: Very cool.  Yeah, this is exactly what I'm looking for.  I see it has a number of innovative features, like multi edit and minimap.  Excellent find!

Comment: great, so select my answer as your chosen answer. (the big green tick)

Answer (score 5):

> a more general level, such that I can use it for many disparate languages, extend it for other tasks

On Windows, the [Zeus editor](http://www.zeusedit.com) can be configured for almost any language and is also fully scriptable making it easy to extend.

Comment: Thanks, interesting editor.  Definitely has many useful features.

Comment: Very nice editor. Love the Brief keyboard emulation.

Answer (score 4):

How about [Yi](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Yi#About)? My impression that its community is currently targeting the Haskell hacker, but is supposed to be like Emacs but based in Haskell rather than Emacs Lisp. Not quite mainstream, but is the kind of editor you're inquiring about I think.

Comment: Yes, that's the sort of answer I'm looking for.  I know many modern editors focus on intellisense and such, but intellisense is language specific.  I'm looking for editors that incorporate some new paradigm that is applicable for general language editing.

Answer (score 4):

I'm really surprised no on has mentioned these two yet:

- [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) (Mac)
- [E Text Editor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) (Windows) (it recently gained vim features, but I wouldn't call it innovative).

Actually most functionality of both editors can be replicated in vim, and I'm sure in emacs, too.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse, Visual Studio and friends are IDEs. Emacs and Vi are text editors. A text editor makes just one component of an IDE. Editors that come with most modern IDEs provide an Emacs or Vi mode. ([Here is an example](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/emacs-emulation-extension-now-available/)). The other way round, Emacs and Vi could be easily extended into a full IDE. (For instance, look at [JDEE](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/)).

Comment: meh. I didn't see anything about it being able to run lisp which is pretty much the __whole point__ of emacs (or at least the origin of its power)

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth please read 'mode' as 'key-bindings'. emacs runs only elisp, and it is highly unlikely that Microsoft would ever integrate a language designed by Stallman into their product. :-)

Comment: Is Emacs "easily" extended into an IDE (like JDEE)? I remember playing around with CEDET+ECB a while back and there were a few quirks to setting it up, though I wasn't really spending much effort for it. Though now I hear Emacs 24 is shipping with CEDET? So maybe they mean to take Emacs that way. On a side note, I'd heard that RMS said he'd like Emacs to take on word-processing capabilities in the future.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is more along the lines of
>   an innovative editor paradigm at a
>   more general level, such that I can
>   use it for many disparate languages,
>   extend it for other tasks, etc.

The [web browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_rich-text_editor) is or will be the ultimate editing tool that can be extended, customized, that is always connected and have all kinds of applications... Pretty much everything can be done through a Web Browser.

As Jeff Atwood said, [Firefox is an IDE](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/04/firefox-as-an-ide.html). With it, and some extensions, you can transform Firefox into the Visual Studio of browsers.

Any web page is an extension of this new kind of "editor". That's why, for example, Google uses it as the main component of an OS (like Chrome OS). The current trend is to do everything on the web.

Comment: Yeah, it's called an editor, not a viitor, or even an emacsitor.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer to your question would be [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org/), [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/), [KomodoEdit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit), [Geany](http://www.geany.org/), TextMate, [NotePad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), Kate, Gedit. I've used some of them at some point before I finally chose to stay with Emacs for all eternity. All those editors except TextMate and UltraEdit are open source and I personally enjoyed a lot KomodoEdit for web development. It also had an nice extension API based on XUL and JavaScript.

The general advantage of this batch of "modern" editors it that they have better support for modern GUI toolkits and better builtin "intellisense" features. None of them, however, is as customizable or as extendable as Emacs and Vim. You won't be able to do terminal text editing with these editors either.

Comment: Thanks, these seem pretty standard though.  I didn't notice any new editor paradigms browsing their feature list.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia's comparison of text editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors).

I've tried UltraEdit, Notepad++, Komodo and a bunch of others and for my money [Editplus](http://www.editplus.com/) is the best of the bunch but it's really a matter of personal taste - what annoys you, what features do you enjoy, etc..

Answer (score 1):

As an example of what you can do with emacs, I just figured out that you can run the git mode magit transparently over ssh and thus interact with a remote repository! Way cool! I have yet to found another editor with that kind of extensibility.

Comment: If I understand right, you simply found a way to interact with source control from your text editor? A bunch of popular software supports that. Visual Studio and KDevelop to name a few. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I usually stick to emacs, even though (quite obviously for most people) i cant use it to its full potential. Past week i had to work on a pc with notepad++ installed, so i tried it and liked it very much. It feels "comfortable", i think, still it cant beat the "raw power" of the classics.